# AS3: Determining whether or not stage.focus is on any textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hopefully an easy question for someone who knows the answer!

In AS3 I'm listening for a users keyboard command, but don't want the command to activate when the user is typing into a textfield. The command is Shift + F, and I don't want it to trigger when someone is typing.

Stage.focus returns an InteractiveObject, and I can't see how to determine whether that is a TextField subclass of InteractiveObject or not. It traces out "[object TextField]".

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator.

```
private function keyboardEventHandler( e:KeyboardEvent ):void {
    if ( e.target is TextField || e.currentTarget is TextField ) {
        return;
    }
    // run the original handler
}
```

Via [the LiveDocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is):

> Evaluates whether an object is compatible with a specific data type,
>   class, or interface. Use the is operator instead of the instanceof
>   operator for type comparisons. You can also use the is operator to
>   check whether an object implements an interface.

So it allows you to check if an object **is** of a certain data type/class, in this case a TextField.